# MemberExpression actual values

Tags: c#, linq

```
class SomeType
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say that I have to create a function that I will call with below notation:

```
var someInstance = new SomeType();
DoSomethingOnExpression(()=>someInstance.Value);
```

where the method should do something like that

```
void DoSomethingOnExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T>> exp)
{
    MemberExpression mExp = (MemberExpression)exp.body;

    SomeType someTypeInsance = ... //from mExp (1)
    String someTypeValueString = ... //from mExp (2)
    string someIntanceMemberName = (MemberExpression)exp.Body).Member.Name; 

    Assert.Equals(someTypeInstance.Value, someTypeValueString)
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

So basically, my question is: can I extract member value from MemberExpression (2) and also if I can extract the instance of type that was an owner of this instance

Comment: What's the part that's giving you trouble?

Comment: Could you provide more information? E.g. what properties does your instance have and what parts exactly you want to have in the `var`'s inside your function. Honnestly, I don't understand the question as it's written now.

Comment: I've rewrite the question. Please check if it is clear now?